# How to change EXCEL 2007 Chart Series Foreground Color for a xlCylinderBarStacked

Tags: excel, graph

I can get it to change for a line chart but cannot figure out how to do it for BAR graphs

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "foreground color"? The **background** color can be changed by right-clicking the chart and choosing "Format Chart Area...", then choosing Solid Fill and setting a Color.

Or do you mean the cylinders themselves? In that case, right click on one of the cylinders and choose "Format Data Series...", select "Fill", then do the same thing I described for the background color.